# Use Ant to launch Java program with cmd.exe "start" command

Tags: java, cmd, ant

```
<exec dir="${basedir}" executable="cmd.exe">
   <arg line="start cmd /c java -jar ${jar.file} "/>
</exec>
```

In Eclipse this does not work, I would like to open my app.
The reason is io.Console because this I can't execute the app in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd` appears in two places: In the `executable` attribute and in the `<arg>`. It should only appear in the `executable` attribute.

Further, the `/c` option of `cmd.exe` should appear before the `start` command, not after.

Try the following:

```
<exec executable="cmd.exe" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg value="start"/>
    <arg value="java"/>
    <arg value="-jar"/>
    <arg value="${jar.file}"/>
</exec>
```